# Webpack gzip compressed bundle not being served, the uncompressed bundle is

Tags: javascript, html, compression, gzip, webpack

I am trying out Webpack for the first time.  I've been using Gulp with Browserify for some time and am pretty comfortable with it.  At this point, I'm just testing out a couple of Webpack plugins.  Namely the compression-webpack-plugin.  I've never used compression before, so bear with me if I'm making any noob mistake.

Below is my webpack.config.js.  The result is I get a main.js, main.js.gz, main.css and index.html.  The main.js is injected into the index.html, but if I open index.html in my browser, it serves the uncompressed main.js, not the compressed main.js.gz.  I had read that I wouldn't need to include the .gz extension in my script tag, and the html-webpack-plugin doesn't include it, so I figured things are working correctly, yet the uncompressed main.js is served, rather than the compressed one.

```
var path = require('path');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './app/scripts/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.scss$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader!sass-loader')},
      {test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader'}
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      hash: true,
      template: 'app/index.html',
      inject: 'body'
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('[name].css'),
    new CompressionPlugin()
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To load `main.js.gz` instead of `main.js` in case of included `main.js` in `script`-tag, you need to configure your web-server (apache, nginx, etc.)

Remember that configuration should load `.js.gz` or `.js` depend on if browser accepts gzip. Web-server can check it in HTTP request header `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate`

In browser devtools you will see main.js in any cases.

Comment: What should I do in the IIs in order to load the PRE-zipped ( not generated ) files ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir You need to write rewrite rule

Comment: I didn't find an appropriate rule for serving gz files for js files

Comment: Thanks for specifying that devtools are showing normal extensions even if is receiving a gzipped file.

I've checked and I've found in response headers: 
    content-encoding: gzip

I think that everything is working without any change, thanks webpack! :-)

Comment: Is it me or is the main question still unanswered: "How to inject main.js.gz instead of main.js into index.html?"

Comment: For IIS configuration, see answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53612311

Answer (score 5):

You can conditionally serve `gz` statics easily with [nginx gzip static module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_static_module.html). The server checks if `app.js.gz` file for e.g. requested `/statics/app.js` is present and serves it transparently. There is no need to change your application or detect `Accept-Encoding` - all that is handled by nginx module. Here is config snippet:

```
location /statics/ {
  gzip_static on;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little late to this thread, but thought I'd add my 2c.  I generated a gz file using webpack, but Apache kept serving the uncompressed one (or erroring if it wasn't present), despite `Accept-Encoding` being set correctly.  Turns out I had to uncomment `AddEncoding x-gzip .gz .tgz` and reload httpd.  For the record, `AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz` was already set, and I'm using Apache 2.4.6 with Chrome 62.  Thanks to Dmitry above for nudging me to look at my conf/httpd.conf file.